# Desactivar campos dependiendo el rol

Tags: html5, asp.net, .net, mvc

Tengo mi aplicación y estoy buscando una forma fácil de que el usuario vea algunos campos de su vista según el rol (html).. Ejemplo

Tengo mi usuario Admin: Este puede ver todos los campos 
Tengo otro como empleado: Este puede ver algunas campos

Estoy trabajando mvc ASP.NET.... ya me puedo logear con mi usuario y clave ... y ya tengo mis roles creados solo tengo que direccionar cuales campos puede ver cada rol

Este seria el formulario con los campos que puede ver el administrador

```
<form id="informacionGeneral" class="contact-form">
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Asunto">Asunto:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="asunto" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Descripcion">Detalle de la solicitud:</label>
                            <textarea name="Descripcion" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Prioridad">Prioridad:</label>
                            <select name="prioridad" class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">

                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Status">Status:</label>
                            <select name="status" class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">

                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Categoria">Categoria</label>
                            <select name="categoria" class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">

                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

<form id="informacionEmpleado">
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Matricula">Matricula:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="matricula" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Nombre">Nombre completo:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Email">Email:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Extension">Extension:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="extension" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Area">Area:</label>
                            <select name="area" class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"></select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Ubicacion">Ubicacion:</label>
                            <select name="ubicacion" class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Y este otro seria el formulario que puede ver unicamente el empleado

```
<form id="informacionEmpleado">
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Matricula">Matricula:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="matricula" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Nombre">Nombre completo:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Email">Email:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Extension">Extension:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="extension" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Area">Area:</label>
                            <select name="area" class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"></select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Ubicacion">Ubicacion:</label>
                            <select name="ubicacion" class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar condiciones en tu vista para ocultar/mostrar según el rol

```
@if (User.IsInRole("ADMIN"))
{

     <form id="informacionGeneral" class="contact-form">
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Asunto">Asunto:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="asunto" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Descripcion">Detalle de la solicitud:</label>
                        <textarea name="Descripcion" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Prioridad">Prioridad:</label>
                        <select name="prioridad" class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">

                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Status">Status:</label>
                        <select name="status" class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">

                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Categoria">Categoria</label>
                        <select name="categoria" class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">

                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

}
@if(User.IsInRole("ADMIN") || User.IsInRole("EMPLEADO"))
{
      <form id="informacionEmpleado">
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Matricula">Matricula:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="matricula" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Nombre">Nombre completo:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Email">Email:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Extension">Extension:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="extension" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Area">Area:</label>
                        <select name="area" class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"></select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Ubicacion">Ubicacion:</label>
                        <select name="ubicacion" class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
}
```

Eso es manera general, pero tú puedes usar las condiciones como mejor te parezca para ocultar/mostrar cualquier parte de la página según el rol que tenga el usuario.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que usted quiere se puede lograr mediante el código Razor. Específicamente, debe de usar `@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager` justo después de `<!DOCTYPE html>` y la declaración `@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User) && User.IsInRole("Admin")`

En el código `@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager` se puede reemplazar `IdentityUser` por una clase derivada de `IdentityUser`.